# Azure Application Insights - create deep link for an exception?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How to create a deep link to an exception found in Microsoft Azure Application Insights? Simply copy&pasting the URL doesn't bring up the exception, I also haven't found a suitable "create link" button or similar.

Comment: What url are you referring to, the one that is found in an alert?

Comment: The HTTP URL of the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a link to the portal afaik. But, if you create a query in  application insights analytics that shows the exception you can! See the "Copy link" button in the upper right corner on the screenshot below.

[image]

This creates a link to the application insights analytics query so be sure to set the time range in the query. If you don't and the time range is set for the last 24h for example, then clicking the link more than 24hrs after the exception won't display results.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that it is not possible in the portal is a real pity, but at least I have some way now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "deep link to exception" is a link to this UX. If this is the case then copy'n'paste the URL should work (if it doesn't work - will be very interested to take a further look why it doesn't).

[image]

Comment: My link looks completely different, when I'm viewing an exception it looks like this: `https://portal.azure.com/#blade/AppInsightsExtension/DetailsV2Blade/DataModel/<some_very_long_blob>/ComponentId/%7B%22Name%22%3A%22sp-appinsights-dev%22%2C%22SubscriptionId%22%3A%<guid>f%22%2C%22ResourceGroup%22%3A%22<resource-group-name>%22%7D` (when I'm using this URL in a different browser session I'm not deep-linked to the exception).

Comment: Link from URL is supposed to work for this blade. Can you please share how you open End-to-end transaction details?

Comment: We'd like to ask a few questions and troubleshoot this problem together if you have time. One option to do it - provide Feedback from this blade and check "allow to contact".